# STM32F411 I need to send a lot of data by USB with high speed

Tags: usb-drive, stm32f4, cubemx

I'm using STM32F411 with USB CDC library, and max speed for this library is ~1Mb/s.
I'm creating a project where I have 8 microphones connected into ADC line (this part works fine), I need a 16-bit signal, so I'm increasing accuracy by adding first 16 signals from one line (ADC gives only 12-bits signal). In my project, I need 96k 16-bit samples for one line, so it's 0,768M signals for all 8 lines. This signal needs 12000Kb space, but STM32 have only 128Kb SRAM, so I decided to send about 120 with 100Kb data in one second.

The conclusion is I need ~11,72Mb/s to send this.

The problem is that I'm unable to do that because CDC USB limited me to ~1Mb/s.

Question is how to increase USB speed to 12Mb/s for STM32F4. I need some prompt or library.

Or maybe should I set up "audio device" in CubeMX?

Comment: For an audio device it would make much more sense to use isochronous transfer, and the usb audio spec.

Comment: What is Mb? Bit or byte?

Comment: @P__J__ I mean bit, bit is always with lower letter. Mb = mega bit; MB = mega bajt. So in this problem i need 12 mega bit per second or 1,5 mega bajt per second

Comment: `bit is always with lower letter. Mb = mega bit; MB = mega bajt.` But you do not use this convention: `This signal needs 12000Kb space, but STM32 have only 128Kb SRAM`. 
 You are not consistent and please **do not instruct me**.

Comment: @P__J__ sorry, you have right. I'm not here to offend anyone, so chill out :). STM32 have 128KB SRAM. So from the beginning: one line - 96k 16-bit samples, 8 lines - 1500KB; 15 packages with 100KB each to send per second (this is not true, because from ADC line i recive only 12-bit samples and i must increase accuracy, but this is not a main problem).
So is it possible to send with speed 1,46484375MB/s by USB in STM32? If no I have another question, if I change number of samples from 96k to 48k, is it possible to send with speed 0,732421875MB/s?
And again sorry if you feel offended :).

Comment: You can send about 0.8MB/s using standard CDC FS STM32 class. I do it in my oscilloscope.

Answer (score 0):

If small `b` means byte in your question, the answer is: it is not possible as your micro has FS USB which max speeds is 12M bits per second.

If it means bits your 1Mb (bit) speed assumption is wrong. But you will not reach the 12M bit  payload transfer.

You may try to write (only if `b` means bit) your own class but I afraid you will not find a ready made library. You will need also to write the device driver on the host computer

Comment: I mean bit. so i need 12Mb/s or 1,5MB/s

Comment: @B.Pieta Your 1Mb CDC assumption is 100% wrong. But you will not get 100% payload bandwidth anyway